# oEmbed, thumbnails and wordpress

Tags: post-thumbnails, oembed

Wordpress has [wp_oembed_get](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get), which I use to get rich media content with [embed.ly](http://api.embed.ly/). I've previously used oEmbed api calls such as [this](http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=DxSQNIc035s&maxwidth=600&format=xml). As you can see it provides thumbnail_url, which I like to use instead of embedding the video. How can I do this with wordpress?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the oembed_dataparse filter to modify the resulting HTML output by any given oembed call.

Example:

```
add_filter('oembed_dataparse','test',10,3);

function test($return, $data, $url) {
    if ($data->provider_name == 'YouTube') {
        return "<img src='{$data->thumbnail_url}'>";
    }
    else return $return;
}
```

Then putting this in a post:

```
[embed]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0[/embed]
```

Will give you a picture of Rick Astley instead of a flash video of him. :)

Edit: Note that WordPress caches oEmbed results in postmeta. So after making your code, you'll have to go and Update a post for it to know to go re-get the oEmbed data and have code like this take effect. In case you want to do testing and such.

Comment: Thanks, Otto! Can you explain what each argument does ($return, $data, $url)? The reason why I ask is because I'm not implementing this in shortcode but rather in my template.

Comment: $return is the normal HTML that the oEmbed process would return. $data is the data received from the oEmbed call to their server, in an object format. $url is the original URL being queried for oEmbed info.