# Video playing from featured image?

Tags: post-thumbnails, videos

If I embed a YouTube video into a post, how do I put a play button over the featured image so that the video can be played without having to open the whole post?

I.e Flipboard the iOS app has a function which allows you to watch videos from the featured image stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens that I answered a [similar Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/74026/12615).
And adapting it a little bit, some serious magic can happen ;)

**Notes**:

- the CSS is being printed inline. It should go with the theme's `style.css` and be adapted accordingly.
- each Featured Image is encapsulated in a *`div`* with `id="videocontainer-' . $post_id . '"`.
- and a Javascript variable in printed together with each FI containing
  `var embedCode_' . $post_id .'  = \'' . $iframe .'\';`.
- then, the FI is replaced with the YouTube `iframe` via Javascript using [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML).
- other notes and credits in the comments.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Featured Image to YouTube Player
 * Plugin URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/78140/12615
 * Description: Swaps the Featured Image by a YouTube player (click to load/play). 
   Needs a custom field with a YouTube video ID 'youtube' 
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: brasofilo
 * Author URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/12615/brasofilo
 * Licence: GPLv2 or later
 * Notes: 
   Plugin skeleton from Plugin Class Demo (https://gist.github.com/3804204), by toscho. 
   CSS Overlay images (http://stackoverflow.com/q/403478), by Tim K. 
   Extracting image attributes from Html (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10131137), by hackre.
 */

add_action(
    'plugins_loaded',
    array ( BL_Featured_Youtube_Thumb::get_instance(), 'plugin_setup' )
);

class BL_Featured_Youtube_Thumb
{
    /**
     * Plugin instance.
     *
     * @see get_instance()
     * @type object
     */
    protected static $instance = NULL;

    /**
     * URL to this plugin's directory.
     *
     * @type string
     */
    public $plugin_url = '';

    /**
     * Path to this plugin's directory.
     *
     * @type string
     */
    public $plugin_path = '';

    /**
     * Access this plugin’s working instance
     *
     * @wp-hook plugins_loaded
     * @since   2012.09.13
     * @return  object of this class
     */
    public static function get_instance()
    {
        NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;

        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Used for regular plugin work.
     *
     * @wp-hook plugins_loaded
     * @since   2012.09.10
     * @return  void
     */
    public function plugin_setup()
    {
        $this->plugin_url    = plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ );
        $this->plugin_path   = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );

        add_filter( 
            'post_thumbnail_html', 
            array( $this, 'thumbnail_to_youtube' ) , 
            10, 5 
        );
        add_action( 
            'wp_head', 
            array( $this, 'print_click_to_play_css' ) 
        );
    }

    /**
     * Constructor. Intentionally left empty and public.
     *
     * @see plugin_setup()
     * @since 2012.09.12
     */
    public function __construct() {}

    /**
     * Filters post_thumbnail_html
     * If the post contains a Custom Field ('youtube') with a video ID, replacement is done
     */
    public function thumbnail_to_youtube( $html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr )
    {   
        $yt = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'youtube', true );

        // Post without YT ID, exit earlier
        if( !$yt )
            return $html;

        // Extract info from the html source
        $atts = $this->get_html_img_attributes( $html );

        // Overlay for Featured Image
        // $click_to_play = $this->plugin_url . 'click-to-play.png';
        // $click_to_play = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/click-to-play.png';
        $click_to_play = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/archive/4/47/20051015080301%21PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png/120px-PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png';

        // Render final output
        $output = $this->get_featured_yt_thumbnail( $html, $click_to_play, $atts, $post_id, $yt );

        return $output;
    }

    /**
     * Print inline CSS in frontend <head>
     * - just for demonstrations purposes, include this in your theme style.css!
     */
    public function print_click_to_play_css()
    {
        ?>
        <style>
        a.gallerypic{
          width:inherit;
          text-decoration:none;
          position:relative;
          display:block;
          float:left;
        }

        a.gallerypic span.zoom-icon{
          visibility:hidden;
          position:absolute;
          left:35%;
          top:35%;
        }

        a.gallerypic:hover span.zoom-icon{
          visibility:visible;
        }
        </style>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Generate the Html for the Featured Image thumbnail.
     * Prints one javascript line per thumbnail (not sure if the best method)
     */
    private function get_featured_yt_thumbnail( $html, $img, $atts, $post_id, $yt )
    {
        $iframe = '<iframe title="" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="' 
                    . $atts['width'] 
                    . '" height="' 
                    . $atts['height'] 
                    . '" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' 
                    . $yt 
                    . '?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>';


        $return = '
            <div id="videocontainer-' . $post_id . '">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById(\'videocontainer-' . $post_id
         . '\').innerHTML = embedCode_'.$post_id.';" class="gallerypic" title="">
                    <img src="' . $atts['src'] . '" height="' . $atts['height'] . '" width="' . $atts['width'] . '" alt="' . $atts['alt'] . '" class="pic" />
                    <span class="zoom-icon">
                        <img src="' . $img . '" width="160" height="120" alt="Zoom">
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">var embedCode_' 
                    . $post_id 
                    . '  = \''
                    . $iframe 
                    . '\';</script>';

        return $return;
    }

    /**
     * Extract image attributes from Html
     * @author hackre
     * @url    http://stackoverflow.com/a/10131137/1287812
     */
    private function get_html_img_attributes( $html )
    {
        $xpath = new DOMXPath( @DOMDocument::loadHTML( $html ) );
        $src = $xpath->evaluate( "string(//img/@src)" );
        $alt = $xpath->evaluate( "string(//img/@alt)" );
        $width = $xpath->evaluate( "string(//img/@width)" );
        $height = $xpath->evaluate( "string(//img/@height)" );
        return array( 
                'src' => $src
            ,   'alt' => $alt
            ,   'width' => $width
            ,   'height' => $height
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your code style. :D

Comment: @toscho, you won't believe how it looked a year ago, I've learned like one Yotaton of great style since being here :o)

Comment: Do I just insert this into the wordpress Loop?

Answer (score 3):

You can't just put a play button over an image and expect it to play a video without some serious magic.

What you can do easily is change the video *oembed* size depending on what the viewer is looking at, for example for the front loop you can have a very tiny (thumbnail size) video that plays, and if they click through to the post they get larger size.

You can add a content filter like the following.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_78140_Embed' );

function wpse_78140_Embed( $content ) {

    if ( is_front_page() ) {

        //return small video, youtube has a cap here so play with it
        $embed_code = wp_oembed_get( 
                                   'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8yBcry1RHU',  
                                    array( 'width'=>200, 'height'=>200 ) );

        $content = $content . $embed_code;

        return $content;

    } elseif ( is_single() )

        //just return the regular size video
        $embed_code = wp_oembed_get( 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8yBcry1RHU' );

        $content = $content . $embed_code;

        return $content;
}
```

In this example the video is hard-coded, so it is advised you add it using a `get_post_meta` or parse the content.

ps. I tried several oembed filters and could not get it to change anything so maybe there is a better solution.