# Save Thumbnails From wp_oembed_get Function

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm using the wp_oembed_get function to display embedded videos on a site I'm working on, what I'm trying to figure out is how I can use wp_oembed_get save the thumbnail of the embedded video to the WordPress library?

Comment: This was answered here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19500/oembed-thumbnails-and-wordpress