# Youtube - Embed as IFRAME

Tags: embed, youtube, iframe

When I embed a YouTube video in the suggest manner (paste url) it adds this as an object. Is there a way to embed as IFRAME instead?

Comment: Maybe try pasting the iframe in the `Text` tab on the editor.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19500/oembed-thumbnails-and-wordpress/19533#19533

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to utilize the latest oembed functions and want the old **iframe** way from any page or post, you can do these:

1. Get the embed code from any youtube video.
2. While editing/creating your post/page, select the **Text(HTML)** mode of the editor
3. Simply paste the embed code

   - As noted by PayteR, this will only work if you are an **administrator** or **super admin** user

Comment: but for this, user must be admin, or superadmin if it's on multisite, because WP it will remove any potential threats like <iframe> <script> etc...